# add new line character whenever date (yyyy/mm/dd) found in a string in python

Tags: python

Below is my python output string, i need to add new line character whenever there is a date format in a string.

**Sample input:**

```py
"2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting the variables in file: /var/workspace/sample.py 2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting SSM variables in file: /var/workspace/test.py 2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting"
```

**Expected output string:**

```py
"2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting the variables in file: /var/workspace/sample.py \n2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting SSM variables in file: /var/workspace/test.py \n2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting"
```

**Display:**

```py
2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting the variables in file: /var/workspace/sample.py
2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting SSM variables in file: /var/workspace/test.py
2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i want to pass this output in a tool, so i have to add a new line character then only it will show the output line by line in UI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Regex --> `re.sub(r"(\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)", r"\n\1", s)`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s= """2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting the variables in file: /var/workspace/sample.py 2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting SSM variables in file: /var/workspace/test.py 2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting"""
print(re.sub(r"(\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)", r"\n\1", s).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting the variables in file: /var/workspace/sample.py 
2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting SSM variables in file: /var/workspace/test.py 
2020/01/08 09:34:18 INFO: substituting
```

Comment: you can use `{n}` to avoid repetition of `\d`: `re.sub(r"(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})", r"\n\1", "2020/01/08")`